# ng-repeat only working in IE

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm busy trying to learn Angular+Typescript+bootstrap and I've stumbled on a problem I can't solve. I have an ng-repeat in a partial view:

```
<div>
<h1>Debtors</h1>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Debtor</th>
            <th class="col-sm-1"></th>
            <th class="col-sm-1"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="Debtor in vm.Debtors">
            <td>{{Debtor.Name}}</td>
            <td><a href="" ng-click="vm.EditDebtor(Debtor.ID)"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Edit</a></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Delete</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With a controller:

```
module Controllers
{    
export class DebtorsController
{
    static $inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$modal'];
    Debtors: Models.TradePartyModel[];
    ModalService: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService; 

    constructor($scope: ng.IScope, $http: ng.IHttpService, $modal: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService)
    {
        this.ModalService = $modal;

        $http.get("http://localhost:51263/api/debtors/1")
            .success((Debtors) => 
            {
                this.Debtors = Debtors;
            });            
    }        
}
}
```

The routing is defined as:

```
$routeProvider.when('/Debtors/ViewDebtors', {
    templateUrl: 'App/Views/Debtors/Debtors.html',
    controller: Controllers.DebtorsController,
    controllerAs: "vm"
});
```

This works perfectly fine in IE, it displays the table and all of the data, but this doesn't seem to work in FireFox or Chrome. I've checked fiddler and the data is coming back correctly, but the table is not showing.

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Any console errors? Have you installed the Chrome Angular extension to verify the scope after Debtors is returned?

Comment: No errors in the Firefox console, chrome gives this as an error: GET http://localhost:51263/api/debtors/1  angular.js:7889
(anonymous function) angular.js:7889
sendReq angular.js:7720
$http.serverRequest angular.js:7454
wrappedCallback angular.js:10655
wrappedCallback angular.js:10655
(anonymous function) angular.js:10741
Scope.$eval angular.js:11634
Scope.$digest angular.js:11479
$delegate.__proto__.$digest VM48:844
Scope.$apply angular.js:11740
$delegate.__proto__.$apply VM48:855
(anonymous function) angular.js:8950
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle

Comment: Not entirely sure how the angular extension works, but It gives three scopes, 1 root scope and 2 siblings scopes under the root scope. The 2nd scope says: This scope has no models, and the third scope has: vm: { ModalService: { ... } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after a few attempts at fixing this, Chrome decided to spit this error out:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Enabling CORS on the server fixed my issue. Looks like its working on all browsers now.